# java mehod to convert an array of chars[][] to an array of int

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I am trying to write a java mehod to convert an array of `chars[][]`, each belonging to an `int array[]`, to an `array` of `int`:

```
public static int charArrayToInt (char[][] Grades, int[] studentList)  {
    int[][] studentGradesInt = new int[10][];       //create a new array to convert char 'grades to int 'grades'

    for (int Students : studentList) {              //for every student
        for (int i=0; i<Grades.length-1; i++ ) {    // for every ref to grade (array)
            switch (Grades[i]) {                    //convert grade in reference to appropriate value in new array
                case 'A': studentGradesInt[i] = '4'; 
                case 'B': studentGradesInt[i] = '3';
                case 'C': studentGradesInt[i] = '2';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I am having a pointer to the reference each of the `Grades[]` but compiler throws "`char[]` cannot be converted to int" on the `switch` statement.

If it helps, my main is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] studentIdList = new int[] {1001,1002,1003};
    char[][] studentsGrades = new char[][] { { 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B' }, { 'A', 'B', 'B' } , { 'A', 'B', 'C' , 'D' }};
    charArrayToInt(studentsGrades,studentIdList);
    System.out.println("grade_test: "+studentsGrades[2][2]);
    System.out.println("grade_test: "+studentGradesInt[2][2]);
}
```

Comment: `Grades` is a char[][], so `Grades[i]` give you a `char[]`, you want to switch on `Grades[numStudent][i]` to get a `char`. And you know that `'4'` is not a int of value 4 but 52, see [ASCII TABLE](http://www.asciitable.com/).?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `char[][] Grades`, so `Grades[i]` give you a `char[]`, to get a specific char, you need to specify the second level index too : `Grades[numStudent][i]`.

A general implementation to read a 2D array is the following :

```
for(int i = 0; i < Grades.length; ++i){ //for each row
    for(int j = 0; j < Grades[i].length; ++j){ //for each column IN THE CURRENT ROW
        switch(Grades[i][j]){
        //...
        }
    }
}
```

Note : You are using a `char` like `'4'` instead of the numeric value `4`, those are different, one is actually `52`, see an [ASCII TABLE](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Note 2 : your student are going to be mad to receive all `'C'` notes. You should `break;` each case when you are done, if not, the next case will be executed.